# Absolute vertical centering causes parts of the div to disappear when it exceeds the browser window vertical size?

Tags: html, css

I have found this vertical centring method which seems pretty common..

```
 #container {
 width: 960px;
 height: 740px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -480px;
 margin-top: -370px;
 }
```

What I'm trying to center here is the entire site, and this code goes perfectly as expected when the screen preview is larger than the div height (larger than 740px). However, Once the browser window is minimized less than div's vertical size (740px) parts of the header disappear above the top of the page.

I can sort of understand why this is happening seeing that 50% becomes less than half the div's size which will be equalized with margin-top.
What I'm looking for is a fix for this issue? Or even a completely different method, I just need to center the site both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a media query:

```
@media screen and (min-height:740px) {
    #container {
        top:0;
        margin-top:0;
    }
}
```

This will only apply the formatting where the screen is at least 740px tall. If you want to learn more about media queries, check http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#container {
  height: 740px;
  width: 960px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

By the way, Smashing Magazine recently published [a nice article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) about this.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute Centering like [Lino Rosa mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19867940/1012919) is the best approach here for easy horizontal and vertical centering while allowing you to add some responsive touches, like fixing your height issue.

Ideally, you should be using percentages for the width and height declarations so that your content will vary with the viewport. Of course, sometimes you just need pixels :-)

Here's what I've done:

```
.Absolute-Center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 740px;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

By setting a `max-height` and `max-width`, the box will never be more than 90% of the container (in this case, the browser viewport) even if it's less than 960px wide or 740px tall, so even small screens see a nice centered box. `overflow: auto` ensures that if the content is longer than the box, the user can scroll in the box to see the rest.

**[View the demo](http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/ipzjC)**

---

If you must have the box exactly 960px by 740px no matter the screen size (forcing the user to scroll around to see all of the content on a small window), then only apply the Absolute Centering styles to `#container` using a media query, like so:

```
#container { 
  width: 960px;
  height: 740px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto; 
}

@media screen and (min-height:740px) and (min-width: 960px) {
  #container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  }
}
```

**[View the demo](http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/JrLdl)**

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. As the height of my element is dynamically changed, I can't give it a fixed height.

Here is a demo below, hope it helps.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
    
#container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.content {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
</html>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
          <div class="content">
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```